# Counting the number of # includes and # define

Tags: c, include, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation

I'd like to use **C** program to find the total number of directives like `#include`, `#define`, `#ifdef`, `#typedef`, etc. Could you suggest any logic for that? I'm not interested in using any scripting or tools. I want it to be done purely using **C** program.

Comment: `typedef` is not a C preprocessor directive, by the way.

Comment: Counting preprocessor directives only is not a very useful metric on source programs, if used alone. (and as H2CO3 noticed, `typedef` is *not* a preprocessor directive).

Comment: Why exactly are you asking? Why purely in C?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch It's just a part of LLOC calculation, that has to be done only with C.

Comment: (I guess it is some homework, otherwise you could use established tools for that). Part of the issue is defining precisely what you want to measure and how you do that. You'll find that LLOC does not have a precise meaning; different tools give sometimes a factor of 2 difference for large free software (like Linux Kernel, Firefox, GCC, ...)

Comment: Yes. You may be right. But, I'll have to find this count as a part of LLOC homework.

Comment: Then you first have to figure out what exactly you want to measure, and how to measure it. My answer might give you some insights. And please inspect current practices, look at what `gcc -H` tells you when compiling existing free software. You'll be surprised. (and `typedef` is not relevant in your question)

Comment: Why not actually **do** your homework, instead of asking people at SO to do it for you?

Comment: @JimBalter You have mistook. Asking suggestions, isn't equal to doing homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store [**all the directives**](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Index-of-Directives.html#Index-of-Directives) in an array of pointers (or arrays).

Read the C file line by line and check if the first word starts with any of the directives in the list excluding any whitespaces at the beginning.

```
char *directives[]={"#assert", "#define#, ......};

int count[NUM_DIRS]= { 0 };
```

Everytime you find a match increment the correspondin index of the `count` array. You can also maintain another counter for `total` to avoid adding values in `count` array.

Comment: Doesn't "the total number of directives" mean that OP wants what I've just come up with? (I'm not splitting hair, don't take me wrong.)

Comment: Counting "total" is not an a difficult task once you have count of each directives. This is flexible in case OP wants to find the occurrence of each.

Comment: Thanks! It's a very simple logic to implement. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't want to parse them, or any other kind of syntactic/semantic analysis, you can simply count the number of lines which start with 0 or more whitespace characters and then a `#` character (losely tested, should work fine):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    char line[1024];
    unsigned ncppdirs = 0;

    while (feof(f) == 0) {
        fgets(line, sizeof(line), f);

        char *p = line;
        while (isspace(*p))
            p++;

        if (*p == '#') ncppdirs++;
    }

    printf("%u preprocessor directives found\n", ncppdirs);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might take advantage that `gcc -H` is showing you every included file, then you might `popen` that command, and (simply) parse its output.

You could also parse the preprocessed output, given by `gcc -C -E` ; it contains line information -as lines starting with `#`

Counting just lexically the occurrences of `#include` is not enough, because it does happen (quite often, actually, see what does `<features.h>`)  that some included files do tricks like

```
  #if SOME_SYMBOL > 2
  #include "some-internal-header.h"
  #define SOME_OTHER_SYMBOL (SOME_SYMBOL+1)
  #endif
```

and some later include would have `#if SOME_OTHER_SYMBOL > 4`

And the compilation command might BTW define `SOME_SYMBOL` with e.g. `gcc -DSOME_SYMBOL=3`  (and such tricks happen a lot, often in `Makefile`-s, and just optimizing with `-O2` makes `__OPTIMIZE__` a preprocessor defined symbol).

If you want some more deep information about source programs, consider making GCC plugins or extensions, e.g. with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) (a domain specific language to extend GCC). For instance, counting Gimple instructions in the intermediate representation is more sensible than counting lines of code.

Also, some macros might do some `typedef`; some programs may have

```
 #define MYSTRUCTYPE(Name) typedef struct Name##_st Name##_t;
```

and later use e.g. `MYSTRUCTYPE(point)`; what does that mean about counting `typedef`-s?